# Java Spring: stored renedered HTML/JSP

Tags: java, spring, rendering

I have a spring applicalation that illustate a list of reports.
Everything works fine. Now i want to call a controller that "generates" all these reports and store them locally. That means all jsp-file should be 100% equally renedered like a browser-response but not returned to the browser but stored locally as an html file.

My idea is:

- user call a url "generate all reports"
- the suiteable controller render all reports in the same why the would call every report individually
- the controller would store each rendered jsp to defined place as an html
- everything will be zipped (works already) and the user get the zip-file with all reports as return

So the concrete question is:

- How can i render a jsp file and store this "rendered return" locally as HTML

Thanks a lot for your respone and help

Answer (score 0):

So final question is:
You want to set up controller and call that controller to save rendered result in local store without returning to the browser.
In this case you can `@Autowire` the controller class and call controller function. When controller is called in another method response will be returned to that calling method not to the browser. You can process returned multipart (html, jsp...) in calling method.